# Bulk Upload of the data In the laravel issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using the Bulk upload of the data in my Laravel through the .xlsx file format, but it is taking around 2 min for the data processing and inserting the 80,000 data in the database

I'm expecting that the data get inserted within 10 sec

This is my controller logic and I think the issue is here only

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the form data
        $request->validate([
            'document' => 'required',
            'cat_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'status' => 'required|in:active,inactive',
            // 'user_id' => 'required|array',
        ]);

        // Get the uploaded file
        $file = $request->file('document');

        // Process and store data based on the category
        // $this->authorize('access', SbiMainUpsReport::class);

        // Process and store data based on the category
        if ($request->cat_id == 1) {
            // Import data using FastExcel
            $data = (new FastExcel)->import($file);

            // Additional processing, if needed
            // For example, you can loop through the imported data and store it in the database
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $report = SbiMainUpsReport::create($row);

                // Attach selected user IDs to the report
                // $report->selectedUserIds = $request->user_id;
                $report->save();
            }
        }

        if($request->cat_id == 2) {
            $data = (new FastExcel)->import($file);

            foreach($data as $row) {
                $report = StatusReport::create($row);

                $report->save();
            }
        }

        if($request->cat_id == 3) {
            $data = (new FastExcel)->import($file);

            foreach($data as $row) {
                $report = PspbEventReport::create($row);

                $report->save();
            }
        }

        if($request->cat_id == 4) {
            $data = (new FastExcel)->import($file);

            foreach($data as $row) {
                $report = PspbircEventReport::create($row);

                $report->save();
            }
        }

        // Store other form data (category, status, user_id) in your database tables as needed

       return back()->with('success','Data inserted successfully');
    }
```

This is my blade code

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Document Upload')

@section('content_header')
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
@stop

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
             @if (count($errors) > 0)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="{{route('document.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf()
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Upload excel here</label>
                                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="document">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Select Category</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="cat_id">
                                    <option>---Select Category---</option>
                                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                                        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->title}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Download Active</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="status">
                                    <option>---Select the download---</option>
                                    <option value="active">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="inactive">No</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
@stop

@section('css')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin_custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert2/11.10.1/sweetalert2.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
  
@stop

@section('js')
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert2/11.10.1/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let table = new DataTable('#myTable');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // show error message
    @if($errors -> any())
    var errorMessage = @json($errors->any()); // Get the first validation error message
    var Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-end',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 5500
    });

    Toast.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'There are form validation errors. Please fix them.'
    });
    @endif

    // success message
    @if(session('success'))
    var successMessage = @json(session('success')); // Get the first sucess message
    var Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-end',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 5500
    });

    Toast.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: successMessage
    });
    @endif

});
</script>
<script>
    function DeleteAlert() {
        var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this data?");
        if (confirmed) {
            // code to delete data goes here
            console.log("Data has been deleted.");
        } else {
            addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }
</script>
@stop
```

Comment: Why do you expect the processing time should be ~ 10 seconds? What is your env? Do you use the right MySQL configurations? Also, you should notice that, if the `StatusReport` is an eloquent model, you are using `Model::create` which creates the model and then `$model->save()` which do the same, which is means that you are doubling the process.

Comment: To further expand on @hassan's comment. What is the filesize of your Excel file? Lets assume your Excel is 2MB, what is your upload rate? Lets say have 1MBs upload rate, this would mean 2s out of your desired 10s is already reserved for just uploading the file.

Comment: @hassan What is solution for this my xlsx file size 10 mb

Comment: If you don't need all the additional functionality provided by `Model::create($data)`, you could chunk the imported collection and use `Model::insert($data)` or `DB::table('table')->insert($data)` to insert multiple rows (1000?) per iteration. This should be a lot faster than your current implicit tx per row.

Comment: So your Excel file is already 10MB - So uploading would already take a couple seconds as pointed out - Why do you think it's the code that is "slow"? Did you consider that actually uploading the file takes most of the time? Doing this in 10s is just not feasible